# chromium compilation after adding new files

Tags: c++, chromium, gyp

I had used some of the API which are part of the chromium files for my application development but are not part of the chromium build (gyp) files.
Ex:- Used the API webrtc::VideoFrame present in                 src\third_party\libjingle\source\talk\media\base\videoframe.cc but this module is not part of the gyp or gypi file. When i tried to add the file to the gyp file its giving inclusion errors for the included files in that module. After adding these modules, its again giving error for the files which are included in those files. How to resolve this issue?

Sample error is copied below;

```
Generating CEF project files...
________ running 'E:\chromium\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe        ../build/gyp_chromium cef.gyp -I cef.gypi' in 'E:\chromium\src\cef'
Enabled Psyco JIT.
Updating projects from gyp files...
Warning: Missing input files:
..\third_party\webrtc\..\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerRequest.h
..\third_party\webrtc\..\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerResponseType.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerState.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerCacheError.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerClientsClaimCallbacks.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerRegistration.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerClientsInfo.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\WebServiceWorkerRegistrationProxy.h
..\third_party\WebKit\public\platform\modules\presentation\WebPresentationSessionClient.h
....
```

Comment: Using following steps to compile the chromium (Using chromium 47).
gclient runhooks
cd cef
.\cef_create_projects.bat
cd ..
ninja -C out/Release cefclient

Answer (score 0):

Chromium has switched to GN so you need to add the new files to a BUILD.gn target.

Comment: Thanks, from which version chromium has switched to GN? I am using chromium 47.